# VS Code API:How to insert text in the bottom of line

Tags: vscode-extensions

I started to create an extension of VS Code and am facing a problem.

As you see in the title, I want to insert the certain text in the bottom of line. To realize this, I tried this:

```
let moveBy = {to: 'wrappedLineEnd', by: 'line'};
vscode.commands.executeCommand('cursorMove', moveBy);
editor.edit(editBuilder =>{
    if (editor !== undefined){
    editBuilder.insert(editor.selection.active, "test");
    }

});
```

However, it does not work well; it resulted in this:

```
//Before: this is the text.
//cursor is between 'h' and 'i'(from 'this')
//After: thtestis is the text
//Omg 'test' is inserted here
```

It seems to me that the cursor did not move and it ended up inserting the string there.
Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Things are being executed asynchronously, try `await vscode.commands.executeCommand('cursorMove', moveBy);`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Finally I solved this problem. Your information helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

While you can await the `cursorMove` command, I think it is better practice to simply compute the `range` at the end of the line yourself. You do not have to await moving a cursor to where you want to make an edit.

You just have to know where you want to make an edit (in case you didn't know you can make an edit anywhere in the document, there doesn't need to be a cursor there already).

```js
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;

// let moveBy = {to: 'wrappedLineEnd', by: 'line'};
// await vscode.commands.executeCommand('cursorMove', moveBy);

// get range at end of line
const editRange = editor.document.lineAt(editor.selection.end.line).range.end;

editor.edit(editBuilder =>{
    if (editor !== undefined){
    // editBuilder.insert(editor.selection.active, "test");
    editBuilder.insert(editRange, "test");
    }

});
```